# Transitions on popover that's injected to DOM

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have some hard time using https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-popover library. I would love to add some transition for the bottom popover but I cannot even find a place that it's using css classes responsible for transitions.

Does anyone use it or know how to do transitions for such solution?
It's hard as there is no element of popover in DOM untill i click on the button.